how close do you have to be to a fixed point, so the function will still converge to that fixed point?
So recently I've been wondering if there exist such an interval $h\in I$ in which $\lim_{n \to \infty} f^n(x^*+h)=x^* : f(x^*) = x^*, f: \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R},\ f^n \iff \underbrace{f\circ f \ldots \circ}_{n \text{ times}}(x), \ f \text{ is continuous.}$
I Found the solution, and the solution was oddly similar to the fixed-point-theorem about the stability of an fixed point. The Interval to the foresaid question is equal to all h's such that $|\frac{f(x+h) - x^*}{h}|\le1$ or in other words, average derivative from fixed point to h has to be less or equal to h. I can give the proof for that if anybody wants one, but I'm more interested in whether this question has been solved(I'm assuming it has to be so), and where i could look for more information about it. Thanks in advance.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How are the $f^n$ defined, or does that not matter? Do they converge to f in some sense at least? Your statement has no limit on h. It is not clear to me what is supposed to be converging to what.

Thank you for pointing it out, the h has no limit, if it had a limit then it wouldn't make sense(it would just be a derivative at its fixed point), the problem looks for an interval consisting of h's such that f will still converge to its fixed point(an error that vanishes during the sequence, for example any contraction mapping from R to R has h $\in$ R, as no matter where will you start the sequence of functions, you will end up at the fixed point. the function has to have a fixed point, and be continuous.

like i said, if you need a proof, that might be less vague, I can do it.

Does the Wikipedia page on fixed-point iteration answer your question? "Common special cases [of the fixed-point theorem] are that (1) $f$ is defined on the real line with real values and is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant $L < 1$, and (2) ..."

I wonder if that line of notation means what you think it means. I'm not sure it means anything. This seems like one of those times a problem needs to be set up in words before you go to the critical equation. It would be a lot clearer if you described the assumed properties of your function $f$ and interval $I$ first, along with the meaning of $f^n,$ then asked if there exists an interval such that ... not sure what, but is the desired outcome that for all $h$ in that interval, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f^n(x^+h)=x^?$

You are getting close votes (not from me) because your question is very unclear. I think you should edit your question to add your solution to the problem, as that may help us understand what the problem actually is.
